# TF set location, frame and frame relation for objects

Tags: ros, frame, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to know how to set the location, frame and frame relation for some objects using TF transform. I have the map of the environment (the yaml file). So only need to label the object in that map, in order to calculate some parameters like distance to the door object and so on. So I know that have to use TF transform but any help how to set the location, frame and frame relation for the object and where to do that? Should I do that in my yaml map file or just in the object node???

Please any help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41210/tf-set-location,-frame-and-frame-relation-for-objects/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should do this using a tf Broadcaster.  See the [first tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials) in the tf package.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0